# DataGrid Focus and SelectedIndex?

Tags: c#, wpf, wpfdatagrid

Having a difficult time understanding this concept.  If you click a row on a WPF `DataGrid` it gets colored with the `SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey` and has "focus."

If you select another control, that row no longer has the `SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey`, but instead some other color (unsure what SystemColor it is).  Yet, it's still considered as the `DataGrid`'s `selectedItem`.

I would have expected that if a DataGrid loses focus that it's `selectedIndex` would always be -1 and `selectedItem` as `null`.  What's the purpose of this behavior, and is there an easy way to turn it off?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose you have a DataGrid and separate "do stuff with selected item" button. How can you make it work if the grid drops selection on lost focus? It's one simplistic example, but overall I don't see how persisting selection state that user made is a bad thing.

Turning it off seems quite easy, just make `SelectedItems.Clear()` on `LostFocus`. You can make your own DataGrid subclass and put it there, so you won't have to write it in every grid. You'll have to implement something more elaborate to make it work with multiselect though.